# Do you have an idea to delete from a certain point (like 3. space) until end in the text in r?

Tags: r, regex, gsub

For a `"for delete 3. space until end of sentence."` string, I am trying to get `for delete 3.` as a result with

```
clear_brand_name <- gsub("^\\s[3]", "", brand_name)
```

This does not yield the expected result.

Comment: `sub("\\s*3\\..*", "",  brand_name)`? Or `sub("(\\s*3\\.).*", "\\1",  brand_name)`?

Comment: It did not work in "ASUS C302CA-DHM4 Chromebook Flip 12.5-inch Touchscreen Convertible Chromebook, Intel Core m3, 4GB RAM, 64GB Flash Storage, All-Metal Body, USB Type C, Corning Gorilla Glass, Chrome OS"

Comment: Do you need 1) https://regex101.com/r/Nb9zD9/1 or 2) https://regex101.com/r/Nb9zD9/2? What is the expected result for `"ASUS C302CA-DHM4 Chromebook Flip 12.5-inch Touchscreen Convertible Chromebook, Intel Core m3, 4GB RAM, 64GB Flash Storage, All-Metal Body, USB Type C, Corning Gorilla Glass, Chrome OS"`?

Comment: expected result : ASUS C302CA-DHM4 Chromebook

Comment: Then you just want to extract the first three words, `sub("^\\s*(\\S+(?:\\s+\\S+){2}).*", "\\1", brand_name)`?

Comment: ok, It is working.thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
clear_brand_name <- sub("^\\s*(\\S+(?:\\s+\\S+){2}).*", "\\1", brand_name)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Nb9zD9/3). `sub` will find and replace the first occurrence that meets the pattern.

**Pattern details**

- `^` - start of string
- `\\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(\\S+(?:\\s+\\S+){2})` - Group 1:

  - `\\S+` - 1+ non-whitespace chars
  - `(?:\\s+\\S+){2}` - two repetitions of 1+ whitespaces and then 1+ non-whitespace chars
- `.*` - the rest of the string.

The whole match (the whole string) is replaced with the value in Group 1 due to `\1`.